# How can I link different MP3 files from an <ul> playlist to the same <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I found a good tutorial on how to build a playlist with HTML 5 `<audio>` tag and JavaScript (http://blog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/).

But when I copy that code into my site, it simply doesn't work well, as every element of the playlist (if clicked) launch a new audio player in a new page instead of being played by the same player above the playlist.

How can I link different MP3 files from an `<ul>` playlist to the same `<audio>` tag?

This is my code

```js
var video_player = document.getElementById("video_player");

var links = video_player.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    links[i].onclick = handler;

}



function handler(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    videotarget = this.getAttribute("href");

    filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget;

    video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");

    video.removeAttribute("controls");

    video.removeAttribute("poster");

    source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");

    source[0].src = filename + ".mp4";

    source[1].src = filename + ".webm";

    video.load();

    video.play();    

}
```

```html
<audio controls id="player">
  <source src="01 Scusate.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  <source src="22 Gli affitti.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<ul id="playlist">
<li class="playlist"><a href="01 Scusate.mp3" class="p">Scusate - Gino Negri   performer</a></li>
<li class="playlist"><a href="22 Gli affitti.mp3" class="p">Gli affitti - Sandro Massimini</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd be very grateful to anybody who is able to find the mistake in JavaScript and suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this functionality on our band's page.

Here's how I did it:

```
/* HTML5 player */
$('#playlist li').on('click', pickSong);

var pickSong = function(ev){
var item = ev.target;
var audio = $("audio")[0];
var pad = 'muziek\\';
audio.pause();
$('#mp3src').attr('src', '').attr('src', pad.concat(item.getAttribute('data-val'),'.mp3'));
$('#oggsrc').attr('src', '').attr('src', pad.concat(item.getAttribute('data-val'),'.ogg'));
audio.load();
audio.play();

$('#playlist li').removeClass('plays');
$(item).addClass('plays');
```

}

This is in the HTML:

```
<audio controls preload="none">
    <source id="mp3src" src="muziek/friend.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source id="oggsrc" src="muziek/friend.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="plays" data-val="friend"></li>
    <li data-val="mercy"></li>
    <li data-val="anouk"></li>
    <li data-val="tmyfml"></li>
    <li data-val="krezip"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Frederik, first of all, thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Hi Frederik! First of all, thank you very much for helping me;).
Unfortunately, I'm not very fond on javascript and scripts in general, so I'm trying to understand your solution.
I suppose you have a folder called 'muziek' inside your site, where you put all the MP3 files you want in the audioplayer.
Friend, mercy, anouk, tmyfml and krezip should just be the songs name, isn't it?
If I'm not wrong, then your solution should work in my site just by replacing 'muzeik' (in the script) with the name of my audio folder, and 'mercy''anouk' etc (in the HTML code) with my songs name.
Am I wrong?

Comment: That's right. Note that my script expects both songname.mp3 and songname.ogg in the music folder. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some difference with your code.
Put one file in audio tag as jsfiddler example and the other file on tag  as  the example.
Try to past the example in you code and  try it. Then, if works, adpt for you needs (http://blog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/)